# change date-taken on photos

Tags: windows, linux, mac, adobe-photoshop, photos

I want to change "Date Taken" on photo, which I clicked using my Sony Ericsson phone.

I have all 3 systems: Windows, Mac & Linux.

You can suggest me software for any one or all.

Is there any way to do it using Adobe photoshop?

or any batch processing software.

Answer (score 3):

This is stored in the EXIF data of the file. There are EXIF editors for many OSes, start [here](http://www.digital-photo-software-guide.com/exif-editor.html).

Answer (score 0):

[exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) works pretty well for managing that data.